# WebView is not working

Tags: java, android, webview

In my simple android application I have a webview filling up half of the screen. All I want it to do currently is load a webpage. The problem is whenever I run my application it says webpage not available. Then if I click on the link (**https://www.google.com/**), where it says the webpage at **https://www.google.com/** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new address it will open the browser and go strait to the website without any problems. Here are some pieces of code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.tscschools;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.jackson"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.jackson.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I heard somewhere when running android 4.0+ or 4.4(Im running 4.4.2), it may cause some problems with the webview? I'm not sure if thats what is causing the problem or not, but I thought I might throw it out there. I really hope whoever reads this can fix it! Thanks!

Comment: Is it giving you any error logs ?

Comment: have you added the internet permission in your mainfest? - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @Sushil, It is there.

Comment: On which android version are you running that code?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong project. lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `WebViewClient` like:

```
 webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/"); 
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);  
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
```

In your case you have to implement `WebChromeClient` and `WebChromeClient` is used to handle a `JavaScript` events in Android App which are produced by `WebView`. The examples of such events are :

```
onCloseWindow
onProgressChanged
onJsAlert
onJsConfirm
onJsPrompt
onJsTimeout
```

Comment: When I copied this over to my code, it gave me an error on the onPageStarted method. It says that Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` line with the following to make sure that you aren't getting an SSL error:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.w("webView", "Encountered an SSL error");
        // handler.proceed();
    }
});
```

You can ignore SSL errors by uncommenting the `handler.proceed();` line, but it would be better to actually resolve the SSL issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see you have not defined WebViewClient for your webview. You have just added WebChromeClient.

Add this line in your oncreate()

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a WebViewClient and setContentView for your browser like this
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    setContentView(web);

```js
package com.example.yourappname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView web;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.yoururlhere.com");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    setContentView(web);
}



public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        
    }
}

//flip screen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}





@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(web.canGoBack()){
              web.goBack();
             }
            else
            {
             backButtonHandler();
            }
            return true;
        }

     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
public void backButtonHandler() {
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    MainActivity.this);
  
 
  // Setting Dialog Title
    // Setting Dialog Message
  
  alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog Title Here");
  alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon);
  alertDialog.setMessage("Exit Now?");
  
      // Setting Icon to Dialog
  // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
  
  alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Exit",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      finish();
     }
  });
  
 // Setting Negative "NO" Button
  
  alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // Write your code here to invoke NO event
      dialog.cancel();
     }
    });
 // Showing Alert Message
  alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a "WebViewClient" and "setContentView" inside your onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) above or below "webView.loadUrl", like this:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
setContentView(web);
```

and you are done. All the best..